# How to iterate over the last IP octet in awk?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I am wondering, is possible to iterate over the last IP octet with `awk`, assuming that IP is a variable received from bash stdin, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
read IP

awk -v IP="${IP}"  'BEGIN{FS="."} {for (i=1; i<=251; i++) { print $1 $2 $3 i } }'
```

And the output will be like:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
....
192.168.1.251
```

Note that this won't work, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf '192.168.1.%d\n' {1..251}
```

This will use the brace expansion of `bash` (originally a `zsh` feature, also available in `ksh93`) to generate numbers between 1 and 251, and for each number the `printf` will print an IP address with the number inserted at the end.

The following would read an IP address and do the same with that:

```
IFS='.' read a1 a2 a3 a4
printf -- "$a1.$a2.$a3.%d\n" {1..251}
```

If you'd wanted to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "." } { for (i = 1; i <= 251; ++i) print $1, $2, $3, i }' <<<"$IP"
```

We want both the input and output field delimiter to be a dot, so we set both `FS` and `OFS` to this character in a `BEGIN` block.  Then we read the IP addresses from standard input, and for each IP address we iterate from 1 to 251 and print out the list.

On the command-line we feed in `$IP` as a "here-string" (originally a feature of `zsh`, but also available in `bash` and `ksh93`).

Comment: Not sure that I follow.. how can I use it within awk?

Comment: Tested and working. Appreciate it! One mini question, so I can not assign `$IP` variable with `-v` param?

Comment: @fugitive Not really. Well, you could, but you would have to split it yourself with `split()` and do the output in the `BEGIN` block. Then you would have to use `/dev/null` as input since the program wouldn't actually need to read anything.

Comment: I see, my first idea was to use `split()` and iterate over array, but that didn't work. Thank you for explanation sir!

Comment: About credit. Both `<<<` and `{1..251}` are features that originated in `zsh`. (though `<<<` was inspired from a similar feature in the Unix port of `rc`, and `{1..251}` is reminiscent of `perl`'s `(1..251)`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I will add that. I don't use `zsh` myself and only dare say anything about things I think I know something about :-)